# Javascript - Use variable RegExp to match multiple keywords in an array of data

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using AngularJS in here. I have no problem matching those words except "C++". Every time I type in "c++" as keyword to generate the RegExp in Javascript and run the matching, I get the error in console as below:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(\bc++\b)/: Nothing to repeat

The code snippet is as below:

```js
$scope.data = [
  {'title': 'Blue Java Programming Book'},
  {'title': 'Red C++ Programming Book'},
  {'title': 'Javascript Dummies Guide'}
  ];

$scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.length = $scope.keywords.split(" ").length;
  $scope.keywordsArray = $scope.keywords.split(" ");

  $scope.pattern = "";
  for (var y = 0; y < $scope.length; y++) {
    $scope.pattern += "(?=.*?\\b" + $scope.keywordsArray[y] + "\\b)";
  }
  $scope.pattern+=".*";
  $scope.patt = new RegExp($scope.pattern, "i");
  for (var x = 0; x < $scope.data.length; x++) {
    console.log("Match [" + x + "] " + $scope.patt.test($scope.data[x].description));
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="keywords"></input>
<button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

I understand that the + sign in RegExp is for matching one or more times of the preceding character, then I tried hardcode the RegExp as below to test and it matches, but not the way I wanted as I need the RegExp to be generated every time I key in the keywords.

```js
$scope.regExp = /c\+\++/i
```

Is there any way to generate a RegExp on the fly with multiple keywords to match an array of data that includes "c++"?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your problem is but you can also represent c++ as c[\+]{2}

Comment: do you want to generate Regex for each keywords in the `$scope.data`?

Comment: @AnuragPeshne I wanted to generated Regex based on the keywords entered in the input and then search for matching ones at $scope.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you'll collect input in var `ip`, you can try this:

```
rrexp = new RegExp('[\\+|\\^|\\-|\\||\\?|\\*|\\{|\\}|\\$]','g');
//rrexp contains all the special characters which need to be escaped

ip = 'c++';
var escapedExp = ip.replace(rrexp, function(fs, matched){
  return '\\'+fs;
});
/*
ip.replace will replace special characters in the 'ip' to be replaced by escaped version of them.
For Eg. + will replaced \\+. Thus 'c++' becomes 'c\\+\\+'
*/ 

var regEx = new RegExp(escapedExp, 'gi');
// this creates Regular Expression based on the ip which matches all exp and is case insensitive.

q = 'Red C++ Programming Book';
q.match(regEx);  //this should output: [ 'C++' ]
```

**Edit**

If you want to create multiple Regex, you can put `ip.replace` and `new Regex` in a loop. Sometime like

```
inputs = ['c++', 'simpleExp', 'complex$one'];
var escapedExp, regEx;
regexList = [];
inputs.forEach(function(ip) {
  escapedExp = ip.replace(rrexp, function(fs, matched){
    return '\\'+fs;
  });
  regEx = new RegExp(escapedExp, 'gi');
  regexList.push(regEx);
});
//regexList will contain all the Regex based on inputs
```

**Edit 2:**
`\b` word boundary cannot match words with special characters.

A word boundary asserts that the position is either preceded by a word character and not followed by one, or followed by a word character and not preceded by one. Thus all the special characters except '_' will not recognised by `\b`.

I can suggest a hack: you need to figure out where in the keywords special characters can appear and then add `\b` according to it. If there are special character in the end of the keyword we cannot add `\b` after it similarly for start of the keyword. If both ends have normal characters then we can add `\b` to both ends.

Here's how I would do:

```
noBAtStart = false;
noBAtEnd = false;
var escapedExp = ip.replace(rrexp, function(matched, offset) {
  if(offset == 0)
    noBAtStart = true;
  if(offset == ip.length - 1)
    noBAtEnd = true;
  return '\\' + matched;
});

if(!noBAtStart)
  escapedExp = '\\b' + escapedExp;
if(!noBAtEnd)
  escapedExp = escapedExp + '\\b';

var regEx = new RegExp(escapedExp, 'gi');
```

Comment: What if I wanted to search for multiple keywords? Meaning that my ip will be an array of keywords to be matched to a sentence. Btw, I don't understand about the `function(fs, matched){ return '\\'+fs;});` Could you explain it further? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your code and the result is the same as what @Crazysheep has posted. I have explain about the problem at the comment under his answer.

Comment: @imationyj I have added comments in the code, hope it explains what the lines do.
Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace to know what parameters the anonymous function accepts.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! and thanks for the explanation on `\b` too! Totally saves my day. :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the special characters

```
for (var y = 0; y < $scope.length; y++) {
  var specialRegexChars = ["*", "+", ".", "(", ")", "{", "}"];

  // For each character in the word, prepend it with \ if it's in our list of special characters
  var chars = $scope.keywordsArray[y].split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (specialRegexChars.indexOf(chars[i]) !== -1) {
      chars[i] = "\\" + chars[i];
    }
  }
  $scope.pattern += "(?=.*?\\b" + chars.join("") + "\\b)";
}
```

Something like that. Note that this solution is pretty verbose, and that list of special chars is very limited.

Comment: The result for the keyword of "c++" is   `/(?=.*?\bc\+\+\b).*/i` right? It return false after I perform the `.test("c++")` function.

Comment: Seems like it won't work when I add a `\b` at the back of the pattern when matching "c++". If I removed it then it can return true when matching "c++" with "c++ programming book", but it won't get the result I wanted i.e.: returns true only if keyword is "programming" when search through "c++ programming book" NOT return true when the keyword is "program" or "programmin" instead